# Sammy loses control of routing when combining back button and history.replaceState

Tags: sammy.js

I am having an issue with Sammy routing, and combining use of the back button with `history.replaceState`. Is there an alternative way to replace the browser's URL without adding to the history stack, and fire a Sammy route other than `history.replaceState`?

`history.replaceState` triggers the Sammy route initially, but if I use `history.pushState`, then click the back button, then `history.replaceState`, it does not trigger the Sammy route.

It also seems to break if I use `location.hash` or `location.href` in combination with `history.replaceState`

I am wanting to use replaceState to control pagination and sorting of a table, but let the standard history stack work for different search parameters and navigating to different pages and back to a search screen.

Edit: I am looking into ways to set Sammy's internal URL without triggering routing.

Comment: Did you get a chance to resolve this? I am having the same issue =(

Comment: Nope, I never found a great solution, and being a work project, got shuffled along pretty quickly. In the end, we ended up throwing out that entire pagination control and condinued to use  https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table, as it works well enough. But it doesn't sit very well with me how much control it takes away from what I want to do with the rest of my model binding.

Comment: What I did was to disable sammy, change the url, and enable sammy again. Works fine for me.      

sammy._location_proxy.unbind();
history.replaceState(null, "", url);
sammy._location_proxy.bind();

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem. Solved with:

```
history.replaceState(path);
sammy.setLocation(path);
```

First- update browser history (sammy doesn't trigger location changes)

Second- force sammy to raise events with new path.

Also custom route logic is needed:

```
Sammy.mapRoutes([{'get': 'myPath', callback}])
```

Callback should parse new path, and if only params after '?' symbol are changed, then pass these parameters to the viewModel's method.

Then inside this method you could handle changes like this:

```
public onParamsChanged({page}) {
    this.myTable.setPage(page);
}
```